# How to make Pretty URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

**I have link**

```
http://musicfoorti.com/categorylist/57/0/1.html
http://musicfoorti.com/fileDownload/75/jhalak-dikhla-jaa-reloadedmp3.html
http://musicfoorti.com/download/75.html
```

and I want to make links look like below

```
http://musicfoorti.com/music.html
http://musicfoorti.com/jhalak-dikhla-jaa-reloadedmp3.html
http://musicfoorti.com/jhalak-dikhla-jaa-reloadedmp3/download.html
```

**Here is my .htaccess code**

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^categorylist/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?pid=$1&sort=$2&page=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^fileDownload/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ /file.php?fid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^download/([0-9]+).html$ /file.php?fid=$1&download [L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/updates\.html$ /updates.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^search\.html$ /search.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you be more clear what url you want to rewrite ?

Comment: I said this in my question.

Comment: I want make look like below link

Comment: http://musicfoorti.com/music.html
http://musicfoorti.com/jhalak-dikhla-jaa-reloadedmp3.html
http://musicfoorti.com/jhalak-dikhla-jaa-reloadedmp3/download.html

Comment: you want http://musicfoorti.com/categorylist/57/0/1.html to rewrite to http://musicfoorti.com/music.html ?

Comment: yes please help me

Comment: it is just example i have more category and i want to do it dynamically.

Comment: please visit the site so you can understand it clearly

Comment: musicfoorti.com

Comment: Only this : http://musicfoorti.com/categorylist/57/0/1.html you want to rewrite ? what about http://musicfoorti.com/categorylist/57/0/2.html http://musicfoorti.com/categorylist/58/0/3.html ?

Comment: Every category have specific name and i want to create  musicfoorti.com/(category-name).html

Comment: Please visit my site and see all link in my website then you will understand

Comment: Suppose when you go music category then the url will be http://musicfoorti.com/music.html or when you go video category the link will be http://musicfoorti.com/video.html etc

Comment: I still do not understand. Please describe what link you want to look how.